# How can I use vertex paint with another material?

Tags: materials, vertex-colors

I made a new model and i followed a tutorial. I made a texture and I want to add some color with vertex paint. I tried it, but it doesn't show up on the render. What should I do? 
Is this possible at all? Sorry, I'm  really beginner.
[image]

with vertex colors:
[image]
[image]

Comment: Did you try the "Vertex Color" node in the shader editor ?

Comment: Yes, i have tried it in many ways but it doesn't show up in the render.

Comment: Could you post a screen of your setup with this node and a screenshot of your viewport while you vertex paint ?

Comment: Yes, I add 2 pictures

Comment: You should edit the factor of the multiply rgb node to a value > 0 because right now the node has no effect